# How do you switch users in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, fast-user-switching

I took my desktop to a PC shop and had them upgrade my PC from Windows 7 to 10.  In Windows 7, my wife and I had separate user accounts. We could simply open the Start menu, open the dropdown next to Shutdown, and click "Switch User". The active session would move to the background and the other user could now log in.

Windows 10 does not seem to have this much needed feature. If it does, it's hidden. How can I switch users in Windows 10?

Comment: [How to Switch User in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7394-switch-user-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Refer to this https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-switch-between-user-accounts-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, open the Start Menu, click your username at the top, then click the username you want to switch to.

[image]

Or use the various other methods [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7394-switch-user-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: It used to be like this but after coming back to the Windows 10 box after some year all of the accounts are no longer listed here. Also on the login screen after boot only one account is shown and it's asking for that account's password. What gives? We can no longer use any of the other accounts on this family Windows computer. Sorry I've not been using Windows for ten years and can't remember if several accounts was a feature that was supported out of the box, maybe it isn't? How would I turn this on?

Comment: Update for the above comment: it seems the Windows box hadn't been updated for a year or more. After going through hours and hours of Windows Update, the accounts would display at the bottom left of the login screen.